# When logging in to SEDE, please redirect back to the original page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer, login, redirection

Pretty straightforward request.

If you're on the query page and log in, currently you get redirected back to the home page after logging in. I would like to be redirected back to the page where the login "originated" like what happens on SE sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guess what .....

This is now done.

[image: oolong approved]

Comment: Your fix has been rolled back at some point, you still got some impact on SEDE?

Comment: Followup report about the return of this issue as mentioned above: [SEDE login redirects to front page rather than returning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256042/335251)