# SEDE login redirects to front page rather than returning

Tags: bug, data-explorer, redirection

Recently, the redirect behaviour of login on SEDE has changed (for the worse). Steps to reproduce:

- When logged off, go to a query page
- Click the "login" link
- Login

Previously, you would be returned to the query page in a logged-in state (ready to run the query without captcha).

Currently, you are redirected to the SEDE front page (`http://data.stackexchange.com/#`) (so you then have to re-navigate back to where you were). The `returnurl` parameter passed in the first few steps is lost somewhere along the way.

Could [the previous "returning" redirect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100698/when-logging-in-to-sede-please-redirect-back-to-the-original-page) be reinstated?

Comment: @Nick this is something that used to work, and not working anymore. How come it's not a bug?

Comment: @ShadowWizard maybe nick upgraded it from bug to FR cos it's now in the dev pipeline - probably a tag based workflow thing.

Comment: Nope, SEDE is open source - Stack Exchange developers don't directly change its code at all, just pull change requests and deploy.

Comment: haha, are you afraid of Nick? (we can rollback IMO, worst case he'll change again and we'll give up, but I wish he would at least explain) - anyway I still think it's a bug, so without any word from the one who changed it, rolling back the change.

Comment: @shadow I thought I must have tagged it as FR originally, so I corrected that, but then I noticed Nick's edit and thought there must be a good reason and give him some time to tell us why he changed it. I too think it's a bug - the behaviour feels wrong, even if it isn't a regression, which it is.

Comment: What's annoying is that it still passes the return URL parameter even though it doesn't use it.

Comment: It seems both Tim and myself have a patch for [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26437791#26437791) ready but we are blocked by [Nick](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135201/nick-craver) ...

Comment: @rene still isn't implemented...

Answer (score 7):

I've created the [Pull Request](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/111) that fixes this annoyance in the Login.cshtml.

What basically was missing was the `returnUrl` query parameter on the action of the Login Form:

```html
<form class="openid-form" action="/user/authenticate?returnurl=@Request.Params["returnurl"]" method="POST">
```

I've tested only with one OpenID provider, the one from Stack Exchange, but I expect the other providers to work the same.

Allow for 6 to 8 weeks to review, merge and deploy by SE staff.

Comment: wow... scarely more than 3 years to fix. btw, I'm surprised that `@Request.Params["returnurl"]"` works - I would have expected `@Request.Params['returnurl']"` to be the way to code it. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[image: Userscript logo]

#### [This userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/8366/data-explorer-sede-auto-login-that-redirects-back-to-original-target-page):

1. Detects when you visit a SEDE page (targe page) but aren't logged in.
2. Automatically logs you in. (Currently only supports Stack Exchange's authorization/OpenID.)
3. Once SEDE is logged in, the script then redirects back to the target page from step 1.

Here's an [install-from-GitHub link](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-misc/raw/master/Stack%20Exchange%20Data%20Explorer%20(SEDE)%20auto%20login.user.js). (Requires the Tampermonkey or the Violentmonkey browser extension.)

For more information, see the [script's home page on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/8366/data-explorer-sede-auto-login-that-redirects-back-to-original-target-page).