# Redirect to the original page after authorization on SEDE

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, authentication

After authorization, https://data.stackexchange.com redirects to the main page.

Could you redirect to the original page (from which I've tried to log in)?

Comment: I have a userscript that works for me and may work for you.  See [my answer at the duplicate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/330545).