# Can we have Data Explorer send you back to the page you were on after logging in?

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, login

If you log in to Stack Exchange from any page (as far as I know) on `https://stackexchange.com` or any sites like `https://scifi.stackexchange.com`, the URL looks something like this and redirects to the page you clicked the log in button on after you log in:

> https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https://meta.stackexchange.com/<sup>1</sup>

However, on Data Explorer, which likes to log me out, there is no such method (I use "Log in using Stack Exchange" and when you log in it kicks you back to the homepage.

**Can we get some sort of system so that when you log in to Data Explorer, you go back to the page you were on?**

<sup>1</sup><sub>if I were sent there by a button, returnurl would actually display as (in Firefox) as `https%3a%2f%2fscifi.stackexchange.com%2f`. I changed it for clarity when reading the question.</sub>

Comment: I have a userscript that works for me and may work for you.  See [my answer at the duplicate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/330545/148310).